# Trying to understand why freading a file over a network is so much slower over Samba than NFS

Tags: windows, fread, samba, nfs, fseek

We have a program building a 3d Model from three files hosted on a Linux file server. Basically x.bin, y.bin and z.bin. It builds the models one z level at a time, and is read each file for every "slice".

On Linux machines running this program, the first slice takes around 45 seconds, and then ~2 seconds for every "slice" after that.

On Windows, the exact same program performing the exact same operation running the exact same script and code takes 5 minutes for the first slice, and around a minute and a half each slice after that.

[Reading file over network slow due to extra reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038577/reading-file-over-network-slow-due-to-extra-reads)

This thread seemed to have a guy with a similar problem, but the truth is that I'm still unclear on how NFS can be faster, as well as how I can suggest a change to the actual developers as to how to improve performance. The code is OS independent, I believe it's just using C's fread, fseek, etc to read the file information over the network.

How does NFS transfer/read data that it can be 60x faster than samba?
How can I get that performance on samba?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure as I don't know much about samba, but my guess is that nfs support fseek and thus can just position over the next splice and return that data. While samba probably doesn't and have to return the full file from the server and discard the "unused" content.

By the way, it's not the exact same program you're running, you probably recompile them right? So it's been transcode to a lot of different system call with each platforms having differents pros and cons...